# Retrieve first few comments on a post from MySQL table

Tags: mysql, facebook, comments

You know how the Facebook home feed lists all the recent posts? It shows the user that posted, their actual post and then the first few comments attached to that post. That's what I'm trying to achieve, but I'm having a hard time building a single query that can gather all that data.

I have 3 tables: Uses, Posts and Comments. Each has a unique ID, but they reference each other's IDs. i.e, the Comments table has columns for the user_id of the user who posted and the post_id of the post it is attached to.

At the minute I'm querying SQL to gather all the posts. I join my Users and Comments tables to learn the Username of the poster and a total of how many comments the post has, like so:

```
$query = "

        SELECT      `posts`.`id`,`posts`.`message`,`posts`.`link`,
                    `posts`.`posted`,`posts`.`category`,`posts`.`user_id`,
                    `users`.`username`,
                    count(`comments`.`id`)
        FROM        `posts`
        INNER JOIN  `users`
        ON          `posts`.`user_id`=`users`.`id`
        JOIN        `comments`
        ON          `comments`.`post_id`=`posts`.`id`
        WHERE       `posts`.`group_id` = '$id'
        AND         `posts`.`category`='$filter'
        GROUP BY    `posts`.`id`
        ORDER BY    `posts`.`posted`
        DESC

        ";
```

But instead of finding how many comments a post has, I would instead like to read the first few posts. Can anyone think of a way to achieve this with just the one query?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `LIMIT` clause to the the "first" posts. By making the "first posts" a subquery and then joining in the comments you can get everything in a single query. The comments should be left-joined in case of posts with no comments.

Notes:

- This query is untested, but it should be close.
- This will get *all* comments for the first few posts, so you'll need to limit the display of "max 3 comments per post" using the front-end display code.
- It may be possible to limit comments to 3 per post within this query using variables, but that's not something I know how to do.

Here's the query:

```
SELECT
  FirstPosts.id,
  FirstPosts.message,
  FirstPosts.link,
  FirstPosts.posted,
  FirstPosts.posts,
  FirstPosts.user_id,
  FirstPosts.username,
  comments.<< your comment column >>
FROM (
    SELECT      `posts`.`id`,`posts`.`message`,`posts`.`link`,
                `posts`.`posted`,`posts`.`category`,`posts`.`user_id`,
                `users`.`username`
      FROM        `posts`
      INNER JOIN  `users`
      ON          `posts`.`user_id`=`users`.`id`
      WHERE       `posts`.`group_id` = '$id'
      AND         `posts`.`category`='$filter'
      ORDER BY    `posts`.`posted` DESC
      LIMIT 20) FirstPosts
    LEFT JOIN comments ON FirstPosts.id = comments.post_id
ORDER BY FirstPosts.Posted, comments.<< column you use to determing comment order >>
```

If you determine comment order by a date or sequence, you'll have to `ORDER BY FirstPosts.Posted, comments.whatever DESC`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the response. I actually use mysqli. Also, my question isn't how to limit my results, it's actually how to get the results. If there are gonna be 20 posts appearing on my page, I don't want to run 20 queries to return the comments, I'd like to fetch all the post data AND the first 3 comments in this one query. I guess it would mean having MySQL return an array INSIDE a row, if it can do that.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood this one. I'll update my answer but note that (a) the query will be untested and (b) it'll get *all* comments for the first 20 posts so you'll have to weed out anything beyond the first three using the front-end PHP code.

Comment: haha gotta admit, this broke my brain for a while (I'm pretty new to MySQL). Think I got my head around it though, made some tweaks here and there and it does the job. Thanks!